# Rollup can't resolve my typings file when trying to build

Tags: typescript, npm, rollupjs

Trying to build my first library, and I've followed a guide to do so. I am using rollup to bundle everything.

The problem a I am currently facing is that rollup complains that it is failing to resolve  my typings file, nut I can't understand why. This is the exact error:

```
dist/esm/types/index.d.ts → dist/index.d.ts...
[!] RollupError: Could not resolve "../../../types/typings" from "dist/esm/types/components/CommentBase/interface.d.ts"     
dist/esm/types/components/CommentBase/interface.d.ts
    at error (C:\Users\Yanay\Documents\Coding\replyke\base\node_modules\rollup\dist\shared\rollup.js:284:30)
    at ModuleLoader.handleInvalidResolvedId (C:\Users\Yanay\Documents\Coding\replyke\base\node_modules\rollup\dist\shared\rollup.js:24491:24)
    at C:\Users\Yanay\Documents\Coding\replyke\base\node_modules\rollup\dist\shared\rollup.js:24453:26
```

This is my package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "@replyke/base",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "dist/cjs/index.js",
  "module": "dist/esm/index.js",
  "files": [
    "dist"
  ],
  "types": "dist/index.d.ts",
  "type": "module",
  "publishConfig": {
    "registry": "https://npm.pkg.github.com/replyke"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "rollup-build-lib": "rollup -c --bundleConfigAsCjs",
    "storybook": "storybook dev -p 6006",
    "build-storybook": "storybook build",
    "tailwind": "npx tailwindcss -i ./src/tailwind-input.css -o ./tailwind-dist/tailwind-output.css --watch"
  },
  "author": "Yanay",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@rollup/plugin-commonjs": "^25.0.0",
    "@rollup/plugin-node-resolve": "^15.1.0",
    "@rollup/plugin-typescript": "^11.1.1",
    "@storybook/addon-essentials": "^7.0.18",
    "@storybook/addon-interactions": "^7.0.18",
    "@storybook/addon-links": "^7.0.18",
    "@storybook/blocks": "^7.0.18",
    "@storybook/react": "^7.0.18",
    "@storybook/react-vite": "^7.0.18",
    "@storybook/testing-library": "^0.0.14-next.2",
    "@types/react": "^18.2.7",
    "flowbite": "^1.6.5",
    "flowbite-react": "^0.4.7",
    "moment": "^2.29.4",
    "prop-types": "^15.8.1",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-icons": "^4.9.0",
    "rollup": "^3.23.0",
    "rollup-plugin-dts": "^5.3.0",
    "storybook": "^7.0.18",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.3.2",
    "tslib": "^2.5.3",
    "typescript": "^5.0.4"
  },
  "peerDependencies": {
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0"
  }
}
```

And this is my rollup.config.js file:

```
const resolve = require("@rollup/plugin-node-resolve");
const commonjs = require("@rollup/plugin-commonjs");
const typescript = require("@rollup/plugin-typescript");
const dts = require("rollup-plugin-dts");
const packageJson = require("./package.json");

// import  from  assert { type: "json" };

module.exports = [
  {
    input: "src/index.ts",
    output: [
      {
        file: packageJson.main,
        format: "cjs",
        sourcemap: true,
      },
      {
        file: packageJson.module,
        format: "esm",
        sourcemap: true,
      },
    ],
    plugins: [
      resolve(),
      commonjs(),
      typescript({ tsconfig: "./tsconfig.json" }),
    ],
  },
  {
    input: "dist/esm/types/index.d.ts",
    output: [{ file: "dist/index.d.ts", format: "esm" }],
    plugins: [dts.default()],
  },
];
```

And this is my `tsconfig.json` file

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2016",
    "jsx": "react",
    "module": "ESNext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "declaration": true,
    "emitDeclarationOnly": true,
    "outDir": "dist",
    "declarationDir": "types",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "rootDir": "src"
  }
}
```

My `types/typings.d.ts` folder & file are located in my src folder, and everything imports just fine other then when using rollup to build

Comment: There's not enough information here. Please show the tsconfig.json